# Generating HGT Files from SRTM 90m Digital Elevation Database v4.1?

Tags: srtm, hgt

This may be a really dumb question and I apologize if it is - this is pretty new to me.

I'm using the HGT files from https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/ with a program currently and want to upgrade to more recent, better quality, data.

I downloaded the SRTM 90m Digital Elevation Database v4.1 ZIP file and see that HGT files aren't one of the formats supplied.

How can I convert what is supplied into HGT files with the same naming convention as what I currently have?

Is that possible or do I need to modify my application to suit this other format?

Comment: Can you add more information about the format of the data you want to use? Or a link to that ZIP file?

Comment: Where is that link of the mentoined file ?